# Prove SLLN doesn't hold for a given series of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers, borel-cantelli-lemmas

The random variable series $\{X_k\}$ is as follows:
$P(X_k=\pm k)=\frac{1}{2}k^{-\frac{1}{2}}, P(X_k=0)=1-k^{-\frac{1}{2}}$. The variables are independent. I need to prove that the Strong Law of Large Numbers doesn't hold.

It suffices to prove $P\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=0\right)\neq 1$ according to the SLLN statement, since $E[X_k]=0$. But I have no idea how to continue the proof. Can the limit be directly calculated? Or there are some other ways towards this problem? Thanks for any help.

Edit: based on michh's hint, I drafted a proof. Define $A_n$ as $|X_n/n|>1/2$, we know that $P(A_n)=n^{-1/2}$. The sum of this probability goes to infinity, so according to Borel-Contelli, $P(A_n\text{ i.o })=1$. So we have

$$P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}\right|>0\right)\geq P(A_n \text{ i.o })=1\,.$$

Thus the SLLN doesn't hold. Is this correct?

Comment: Are the $X_k$ independent?

Comment: @Michh Yes, I will add it to the question. Sorry for forgetting this.

Comment: Hint: use the second Borel-Cantelli lemma

Comment: @Michh I added my proof to the question. Could you please check it?

Comment: Yes, this seems good.

Comment: To be completely rigorous I would write $P\left(\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}\nrightarrow 0\right)$ instead of $P\left(\lim \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n} >0\right)$ as the limit does not necessarily exist. Otherwise it's all good!